# Android: on orientation change the cursor disappears

Tags: android

Android: on orientation change the cursor disappears. I have two edit boxes. I have defined onConfigurationChanged. In this function I reload the layout as I have different layout for landscape and portrait. Rest works fine except the cursor.

Comment: what do you mean with cursor? a cursor to a database result set or the cursor on a text to determine where you will write?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for a very quick response. By cursor I mean the cursor on the text. 
I have entered some text on the edit box then I change the orienation, the text is restored but the cursor is not more there.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />  <!-- it should reslove your issue -->
</EditText>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed the problem of cursor disappearing. But now I got another issue here is that the cursor goes back to the original position, does not stay at where it was when I change the orientation.

Comment: Its not possible, if you change the Orientation.

Comment: I see it works fine in other apps where they have different layouts.